# Is it possible to obtain the right root by calling getRoot() from a Path objetct refering to a relative path?

Tags: java, path, nio

From the method [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getRoot()) we have: "Returns the root component of this path as a Path object, or null if this path does not have a root component"

How it doesn't make a distinction between absolute and relative path, makes me think it works, but I'm not completely sure of that.

P/D I know this could be figured out by executing a few lines of code, still think it's a relevant question, specially if you are studying a java certification.

Comment: This type of question, that can be easily resolved by carefully reading the Javadoc and, if still uncertain, writing a few lines of code, is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JimGarrison reading carefully the documentation you can figure it out almost all the questions of stackoverflow the strong point here, I think is to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible since a relative path does not have a root component. Here is an example:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class PathChecker {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        Path relative = Paths.get("myFile.txt");
        Path absolute = Paths.get("//home//denis//workspace//ocp//myFile.txt");
        System.out.println("Relative path: " + relative + " -> root: " + relative.getRoot());
        System.out.println("Absolute path: " + absolute + " -> root: " + absolute.getRoot());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output from executing that ("myFile.txt" is in the current program folder):

> Relative path: myFile.txt -> root: null
>
> Absolute path: /home/denis/workspace/ocp/myFile.txt -> root: /